# Is it possible in wxwidgets to determine if the window is currently visible?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython, wxwidgets, polling

In my wxWidgets (wxPython) app, I am using a 50 ms timer to do some polling and update a window if there are any changes. If changes are detected it calls `wxWindow.Refresh` to update the window, and the actual updating of the widgets is done in the `EVT_PAINT` handler. It would be nice if I could disable the painting and/or the timer if the user is not looking at the window anyway. However EVT_PAINT is still being fired even if the window is iconized or hidden behind a different window.

Is there any way to detect if the window is not currently visible on screen, or to prevent EVT_PAINT events from firing unnecessarily?

There is the `IsActive` method and the `EVT_ACTIVATE` event to test whether the window has focus, but I want to keep updating the window if it is unfocussed but still visible. The `wxWindow.IsShown` family of functions doesn't help, they still return True for hidden/iconized windows.

Comment: I have the same problem: a widget is updated repeatedly with a wxTimer, but it should not be updated if the window is not visible, for example when placed in an inactive wxNotebook tab. I could use IsShownOnScreen in the event handler to stop any further events, but there is no way to start it again once it becomes visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

[IsShownOnScreen()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a72d70fd14e3565bf782fbcd3271d8930) could help with the iconized case. **Edit: But actually does not**.

Or you could trap `wxEVT_ICONIZE` to detect when the window is minimized.

But to be honest I'm rather surprised that refreshing a window hidden behind another one still results in a repaint. If the window in front is not transparent, this really shouldn't happen.

Comment: Does not work. It's exactly what I tried for the refresh timer.

Comment: IsShownOnScreen does only check if alement and all it's parents are hidden or not. It does not check the state of the window.

Comment: Sorry, `IsShownOnScreen()` indeed doesn't work correctly (at least IMHO it should work like I wrote, but, again, currently it doesn't) in this case. `wxEVT_ICONIZE` definitely does though.